# Moving file makes server unresponsive

Tags: linux, networking, samba, windows-server-2012

I've configured a backup job where I'm moving a larger file (80GB) from a debian linux machine to a Windows 2012 Server (mount windows share with samba).

The thing is, as soon as the movement of the file starts, the server gets more or less unresponsive (e.g., ping is only answering sporadically, connection lost, clients can not login to the server, etc.) until it is finished.

The behavior seems to me a bit strange. I know that moving the file uses almost complete bandwidth, but shouldn't the server, albeit more slowly, at least handle the other connection requests? Are there any samba or windows server settings to prevent such behaviour?

Comment: Are you using Server 2012 or Samba (which only runs on *nix)??

Comment: You are likely running into IO contention. Watch disk-related performance counters while you're doing this copy - my guess is that IO request latency goes through the roof when you're copying.

Answer (score 2):

You can try to limit bandwidth used by backup process.

```
tar cvf - /files/to/backup | pv -L 512k > /your/file/on/sshfs
```

or, if archive already created:

```
cat backup.tgz | pv -L 512k > /your/file/on/sshfs
```